# Почему метод Show у Editor Window работает некорректно?

Tags: c#, unity3d

[В документации сказано](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.Show.html), что метод `EditorWindow.Show` открывает окно EditorWindow. Замечательно. Создаю я два класса:

первый

```
public class WindowOne : EditorWindow {

    public static WindowOne windowOneInstance;

    [MenuItem("Window/Open Window One")]
    public static void Init() {
        windowOneInstance = GetWindow<WindowOne>(false, "Window One", true);
    }
}
```

второй

```
public class WindowTwo : EditorWindow {

    public static WindowTwo windowTwoInstance;
    public static WindowOne windowOneInstance;

    [MenuItem("Window/Open Window Two")]
    public static void Init() {
        windowTwoInstance = GetWindow<WindowTwo>(false, "Window Two", true);
        windowOneInstance = WindowOne.windowOneInstance;
    }

    public void OnGUI() {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 50), new GUIContent("show window one"))) {
            windowOneInstance.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Всё очень просто: в меню я кликаю по `Open Window One`, затем по `Open Window Two`, чтобы открыть два окна и затем одно из них (Window One) я закрываю:

[image]

Теперь, если во втором окне я кликаю кнопку "show window one", то первое окно не появляется. Точнее появляется какая-то однопкисельная точка, которую нельзя ни увеличить в размерах, ни сдвинуть с места, ни что-то еще

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я пишу `GetWindow(typeof (WindowOne));` вместо `.Show()` - то окно показывается, но я не уверен, что это то же самое окно, что было в начале, потому что `instanceID` этого окна будет отличаться от того, что было изначально.

---

Собственно, почему метод `Show` работает так странно? Что я делаю не так? И что мне нужно сделать, чтобы показать тот же самый экземпляр окна, который был закрыт (временно скрыт) ранее?

Версия *Unity* - 5.6.0p4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если закрыл окно, то показать потом его снова уже нельзя, ссылка становится **null**. А пиксель который показывает, это болванка создается, и растянуть ее можно, если потянуть в верхний левый угол(на маке не уверен), там окно будет с пометкой **"Failed to load"**.
В том числе **EditorWindow** это **ScriptableObject**. И вот что делает функция **Show**:

```
public void Show()
    {
        this.Show(false);
    }

    public void Show(bool immediateDisplay)
    {
        if (this.m_Parent == null)
        {
            EditorWindow.CreateNewWindowForEditorWindow(this, true, immediateDisplay);
        }
    }
```

Ну и видимо при закрытии он ставит размер окна EditorWindow минимальными. И при повторном открытии получаешь пустое окно с минимальными размерами(насколько позволяет ОС).

Выход: EditorWindow использовать как болванку для отображения, а данные и действия брать из своих статических скриптов.

Comment: Да, я в итоге пришел к такому же выводу. Хотя странно наблюдать метод `Show` и при этом отсутствие  метода `Hide`, а метод `Close`, работающий как `Destroy` >_<

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Юнитеки видимо ограничили все окна как дочерние, и так как у них нет собственного трея для окон, не стали заморачиваться с сохранением/сворачиванием их. Да и пользователя спасли от мусора лишнего, свернул и забыл, а окно память продолжает кушать. Может когда-нибудь, не в нашу эру, это произойдет.